# Display a string with today's date in text area

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to display a string along with today's date in a text area. I have the below html. I've done some research with previous questions but nothing is working. Can anyone please tell how to do it? I'm new here.

```
<tr>
  <th>
    <label>Title/Purpose*</label>
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
      <input type="text" class="col-md-10" ng-model="arform.revtitle" required/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: where is your string stored? in `arform.revtitle`? and do you want to show the date inside input? should a user be able to edit it?

Comment: May you should try with value attribute of  `<input type="text" value=" Date()">' element. Date() is taken as example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to get the current date and output the result.

```
var d = new Date(),
    month = d.getMonth() + 1,
    date = d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear(),
    area = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];

area.value = month +"/"+ date +"/"+ year;
```

See the attached JSFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/9t62pvga/

Answer (score 0):

define the variable in your controller and set it in the ng-model attribute:

```
$scope.today = new Date();

<input type="text" class="col-md-10" ng-model="today" required/>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vdME9Fmqj7xBvzhpF0a6?p=preview